# Eclipse Generating invalid Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently working on an android project for school named MyContactList and at first when I generated new Activities it worked fine.
However, now when I generate new Activities it pops out a ton of errors.
How do I go about generating a new activity: Right click com.example.mycontactlist under source > new > other > android activity > blank activity.

It generates the files fine. However, after generating, it shows these errors:

[image: Problems/Errors]

The code generated in the old Activities and in the new one is different.

Old:

```
package com.example.mycontactlist;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContactMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

New:

```
package com.example.mycontactlist;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ContactSensorActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_sensor);
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_sensor, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I tried copying and pasting an old Activity and changing the code around to use as a new one.
I also tried creating one from scratch but each time it crashes and I am unable to find what the error is due to.

I have to test on my cellphone and currently do not know how to get it to notify me of crash errors.

The reason I can't check it in the emulator is due to an old issue I had with google play services and my app: it didn't like my app and wouldn't update, so I run tests that have to do with the map portion of my code on my cellphone.

My question is: how do I get it to generate an Activity like my old one?

Eclipse is generating different code than I expected when creating a new Activity.

Comment: if you have command prompt, please move to the adb tool directory, and try using adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S for getting error log

Comment: Eclipse was deprecated in mid-2015. Why are you using it?

Comment: @S.W. App can't compile. There is no logcat.

Comment: Go and download an app-compat-v7 library project and import into Eclipse, then simply add the library project as your project dependency

Answer (score 0):

You are creating different types of activities. You can learn about different types of activities here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates.html 
I think you are creating a Navigation Drawer activity.

Comment: NavigationDrawer isn't imported. Why do you think that? It's a Google Map Fragment...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Android Studio or convince your professor/class that it is the tool to use. Eclipse has long been abandoned for Android development. The **code** is what you are learning anyway, not the tool to compile it.
2. There is no way an empty / blank Activity template creates that "old" code. That is a Google Map activity.
3. `android.app.support.v7` libraries are missing. The majority of your compilation errors relate to that. You are missing a JAR file (since you are using Eclipse) or a Gradle dependency (if you even use Gradle).
4. `activity_contact_sensor.xml` have been generated by the IDE tools. It also should be able to resolve if the remainder of your code can compile.

**tl;dr** Not sure how that "old" code was generated. Use Android Studio